# Custom webpart to display HTML form which supports adding additional dataRow on the fly?

Tags: development, web-part, custom-form, visual-web-part

Would like to build a WebPart which will display an HTML form(allow the users to add the data rows as many as required) and will insert the data into the SharePoint list on the submit (based on http://feedbackWP.codeplex.com)

[image]

Add Row should bring another row as

[image]

On Submit, I should be able to fetch all the values and update the corresponding SharePoint 2010 List.

What would be the best way to achieving this? Can I use something like Grid or should I build my own HTML components and take care of the repeating?

Note: Field value of Code should be brought from the another List.

Comment: Adding a row is quite easy in InfoPath forms, if you have an option.. use InfoPath.. Also you can have multiple data sources so it won't be an issue

Comment: Infopath multiple rows get added as a single row to the list (stored in xml), so not useful in this situation.

Comment: Infopath has been deprecated. [Here](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/04/options-to-create-forms-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Just because it is deprecated doesn't mean its unusable for the forseeable future. XML based web services are deprecated but still usable in 2013. Expect InfoPath to be around for about 10 more years.

Comment: does it mean that we may built the Infopath form which may submit multiple list entries at once? At least in this case, does not it save the info as .xml file as multiple list entries are expected?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Knockout JS to bind your inputs and jQuery to submit/create SPList items.

here is an example of knockout dynamic row binding:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Personally i try to stay away from SPServices and rather use OOB JavaScript api's.

Infopath is almost dead, i wouldn't invest my time creating forms etc with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to do this is to code something in JQuery using SPServices to call the client side object model. Jquery can easily add the repeating functionality to the form and each "row" can be submitted to the list individually using SPServices calls.